# Missing edge points in ListDensityPlot in Wolfram Mathematica plots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mesh, density-plot

I searched this for hours but can't find the workaround for this problem.

What would be the command to make the function ListDensityPlot in Mathematica to show the endpoints of the plot like in the MatrixPlot function?

[Plot using ListDensityPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED5Ja.png)

[Plot of the same data with MatrixPLot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWmmR.png)

Both figures were made with the minimal working example:

```
nx = 20;
ny = 20;

Table[
  u[[i]][[j]] = Exp[-(i - nx/2)^2 - (j - ny/2)^2]
  , {i, 2, nx - 1}, {j, 2, ny - 1}];

Table[u[[i]][[1]] = 1; u[[i]][[ny]] = 1;, {i, nx}];
Table[u[[1]][[j]] = 1; u[[nx]][[j]] = 1;, {j, ny}];

ListDensityPlot[u, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
MatrixPlot[u]
```

I expected the plot to produce one colored square for each mesh point, but apparently the final ones are missing with ListDensityPlot.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListDensityPlot` is offset due to the `InterpolationOrder -> 0`.

For example.

```
GraphicsRow[{
  ListDensityPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}},
   Mesh -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0],
  ListDensityPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}},
   Mesh -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 1]}]
```

Without `InterpolationOrder -> 0` there is no offset problem.

```
nx = 20;
ny = 20;

u = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, ny}];

Table[u[[i]][[j]] = Exp[-(i - nx/2)^2 - (j - ny/2)^2],
  {i, 2, nx - 1}, {j, 2, ny - 1}];

Table[u[[i]][[1]] = 1; u[[i]][[ny]] = 1;, {i, nx}];
Table[u[[1]][[j]] = 1; u[[nx]][[j]] = 1;, {j, ny}];

ListDensityPlot[u, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
MatrixPlot[u]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, although I need the figure without Interpolation to analyze the raw data. That could be a temporary solution.